# Calendar Dropbox in Experiment Window in Anylogic

Tags: calendar, dropdown, anylogic

Is there a way to have a Calendar (and Time) dropdown that can be put into the Experiment (Simulation) window of Anylogic?

I have users that will input a table (database) of delivery items with date/time elements I need to compare and use during the simulation.

I know I can change the Model Time property, but the user doesn't want to have to change the underlying model in any way; he wants the Simulation interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is no build-in way to do this but you should be able to use the `DatePicker` class for this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html